# Filter a RANKX measure

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, rank, measure

I have a table in Power BI like that:

```
Year    Company Country Revenue
2019    XXX     Brazil  1029029
2018    YYY     France  1029100
2019    ZZZ     Brazil  1929201
2017    XXX     Brazil  8291020
```

I cooked the following measure:

```
RANKX(ALL(
'Data'[Company];
'Data'[Country]);
CALCULATE(SUM('Data'[Revenue]);'Data'[Year]=2019))
```

I want to build a table visual on Power BI which consider only company 'XXX' rank position for every country.

If I drop this measure on a Power BI Table as a column, I need to filter this Table to consider only company 'XXX'. I want to know if it's possible to consider this filter for company in my measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your measure and filter your visual by `XXX`. This is your measure at the moment, with and without the filter. Here you just dont display the filtered rows and the result is the same:

[image]

[image]

If you change your measure like this you get the right result with the filter, you get different results for the rank:

[image]

[image]

You can put the `XXX` filter also in your table visual and not directly on the report. This way it is more hidden.

Comment: I would like to insert that filter inside the measure and not have to apply it in my table visual or report visual. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can use something like this: `Rankx(Allselected('Table'); Calculate(Sum('Table'[Column4]); 'Table'[Column1] = 2019 && 'Table'[Column2] = "XXX"))`